# Magento error: Module "Mage_Api" requires module "Mage_Core"

Tags: magento

my production site gone away and for no reason. I know last extension I have installed, but that was three days ago. I get this error on every page:

```
a:4:{i:0;s:46:"Module "Mage_Api" requires module "Mage_Core".";i:1;s:702:"#0 /app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/Config.php(804): Mage::throwException('Module "Mage_Ap...')
#1 /app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/Config.php(769): Mage_Core_Model_Config->_sortModuleDepends(Array)
#2 /app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/Config.php(315): Mage_Core_Model_Config->_loadDeclaredModules()
#3 /app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/App.php(396): Mage_Core_Model_Config->loadModules()
#4 /app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/App.php(329): Mage_Core_Model_App->_initModules()
#5 /app/Mage.php(627): Mage_Core_Model_App->run(Array)
#6 /index.php(87): Mage::run('', 'store')
#7 {main}";s:3:"url";s:1:"/";s:11:"script_name";s:10:"/index.php";}
```

What can I do to return my production site to work?

P.S. Mage_Core is not disabled in core_config_data.
Magento 1.5.1.0

**SOLVED**: I had wrong permissions on my config files under app/etc folder.

Comment: Did you tried to disable last installed module?

Comment: This error prevents me from accessing to backend, but I created core_config_data entry, that disables output of this module, but this not helps.

Comment: You should try to disable module using it's xml config file (disable module output will not help, because module is being loaded in this case)

Comment: Your hint pointed me to solution - I had wrong permissions on my config files. I have changed them few days ago. So after clearing magento cache today, problem occured.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should check permissions of you module's config file.