# Module "Mage_Api" requires module "Mage_Core" error in magento

Tags: php, magento

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Magento error: Module “Mage_Api” requires module “Mage_Core”](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10547281/magento-error-module-mage-api-requires-module-mage-core)

error list when I open site:

```
Module "Mage_Api" requires module "Mage_Core".

Trace:
#0 /home/towelsjt/public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/Config.php(849): Mage::throwException('Module "Mage_Ap...')
#1 /home/towelsjt/public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/Config.php(812): Mage_Core_Model_Config->_sortModuleDepends(Array)
#2 /home/towelsjt/public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/Config.php(315): Mage_Core_Model_Config->_loadDeclaredModules()
#3 /home/towelsjt/public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/App.php(414): Mage_Core_Model_Config->loadModules()
#4 /home/towelsjt/public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/App.php(343): Mage_Core_Model_App->_initModules()
#5 /home/towelsjt/public_html/app/Mage.php(683): Mage_Core_Model_App->run(Array)
#6 /home/towelsjt/public_html/index.php(87): Mage::run('', 'store')
#7 {main}
```

Comment: yes but, there is not clear solution :(

Comment: change the permissions of your config file in app/etc/modules using chmod

Comment: hey, change permission to 777 but still error display

Comment: is this a new install or an existing site? did you just copy the code to a different server?

Comment: yes, I just copy to different server

Comment: I had the same problem when moving to a new server. I my case I had local some files with zero bytes (cause they were in dropbox only online). So I uploaded some empty files to the new server = problem

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This error message is letting you know that Magento tried to load the `Mage_Api` module's declaration, but couldn't find a declaration for the `Mage_Core` module.  Since `Mage_Api` is configured to depend on this module, Magento bails.

There's myriad reasons this could happen, and there's not enough information in your question to deduce what's going on. You'll need to debug this problem further yourself.

First, this exception is emanating from the following method

```
#File: app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/Config.php
protected function _sortModuleDepends($modules)
{
    ...
}
```

The `$modules` array contains the loaded `app/etc/modules` information for your system.  Your exception comes up in the first loop

```
foreach ($modules as $moduleName => $moduleProps) {
    $depends = $moduleProps['depends'];
    foreach ($moduleProps['depends'] as $depend => $true) {
        if ($moduleProps['active'] && ((!isset($modules[$depend])) || empty($modules[$depend]['active']))) {
            Mage::throwException(
                Mage::helper('core')->__('Module "%1$s" requires module "%2$s".', $moduleName, $depend)
            );
        }
        $depends = array_merge($depends, $modules[$depend]['depends']);
    }
    $modules[$moduleName]['depends'] = $depends;
}
```

Check the contents of `$modules`.  If there's not a `Mage_Core` key (as I suspect), that means Magento couldn't load the file in `app/etc/modules` that declares `Mage_Core`.  By default this is `Mage_All.xml`.  Check permissions on this file, and check that it's valid XML.  If cursory checks pass, this file is loaded in `_loadDeclaredModules`

```
protected function _loadDeclaredModules($mergeConfig = null)
{
    //...
    foreach ($moduleFiles as $file) {
        $fileConfig->loadFile($file);
        $unsortedConfig->extend($fileConfig);
    }    
    $moduleDepends = array();
    foreach ($unsortedConfig->getNode('modules')->children() as $moduleName => $moduleNode) {
        if (!$this->_isAllowedModule($moduleName)) {
            continue;
        }

        $depends = array();
        if ($moduleNode->depends) {
            foreach ($moduleNode->depends->children() as $depend) {
                $depends[$depend->getName()] = true;
            }
        }
        $moduleDepends[$moduleName] = array(
            'module'    => $moduleName,
            'depends'   => $depends,
            'active'    => ('true' === (string)$moduleNode->active ? true : false),
        );
    }

    //...
}
```

Determine why the `Mage_Core` node is missing, and you'll find the solution to your problem.

Comment: @wiramrathod Did you end up finding the cause of this?  I'd hate for a second question to not have a specific answer :)